# Angularjs unit test resolve promise inside custom directive with external template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angular-promise, angularjs-templates

I have a custom directive that uses an external template and is passed data from a service. I decided to ensure that the promise was resolved before modifying the data, which was fine in the actual code but broke my unit tests, which is annoying. I have tried a number of variations but am now stuck. I am using 'ng-html2js' preprocessor.

Here is the unit test

```
describe('ccAccordion', function () {
var elm, scope, deferred, promise, things;
beforeEach(module('ccAccordion'));
// load the templates
beforeEach(module('components/accordion/accordion.html'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $q) {
    elm = angular.element(
      '<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>'
      );
    scope = $rootScope;
    things = [{
            title: 'Scifi',
            description: 'Scifi description'
        }, {
            title: 'Comedy',
            description: 'Comedy description'
        }];

    deferred = $q.defer();
    promise = deferred.promise;

    promise.then(function (things) {
        scope.items = things;   
    });

    // Simulate resolving of promise
    deferred.resolve(things);

    // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
    scope.$apply();

    // compile the template?
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should create clickable titles', function () {
    var titles = elm.find('.cc-accord h2');

    expect(titles.length).toBe(2);
    expect(titles.eq(0).text().trim()).toBe('Scifi');
    expect(titles.eq(1).text().trim()).toBe('Comedy');
});
```

I have left out the custom addMatchers and the rest of the tests. The error I get is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.items.$promise')
```

Here is the directive

```
var ccAccordion = angular.module("ccAccordion", []);
ccAccordion.directive("ccAccordion", function () {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "components/accordion/accordion.html",
    scope: {
        items: "="
    },
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.items.$promise.then(function (items) {
            angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
                item.selected = false;
            });
            items[0].selected = true;
        });

        scope.select = function (desiredItem) {
            (desiredItem.selected === true) ? desiredItem.selected = false : desiredItem.selected = true;
            angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
                if (item !== desiredItem) {
                    item.selected = false;
                }
            });
        };

    }
};
```

});

This is where the directive is used in main.html

```
<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>
```

In the main controller the genres service is passed in ie

```
 angular.module('magicApp')
.controller('GenresCtrl', ['$scope', 'BREAKPOINTS', 'Genre', 
function ($scope, BREAKPOINTS, Genre) {
    $scope.bp = BREAKPOINTS;
    $scope.genres = Genre.query();
}]);
```

Comment: I think your point of confusion here is that you're not mocking the behavior of the service, and some of your code is missing from the example you gave.

I don't think you're including the line of code where that exception actually arises, and I assume it's your test for if the promise is resolved or not.

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code

Comment: The tests fail on the first test, 'it should create clickable titles'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I would move that code you put in link into the controller. The data processing should probably happen in a service. I know you've been told big controllers are bad, but big linking functions are generally worse, and should never do that kind of data processing.

```
.controller('GenresCtrl', ['$scope', 'BREAKPOINTS', 'Genre', 
function ($scope, BREAKPOINTS, Genre) {
    $scope.bp = BREAKPOINTS;
    $scope.genres = Genre.query().then(function (items) {
        angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
            item.selected = false;
        });
        items[0].selected = true;
    });

    scope.select = function (desiredItem) {
        (desiredItem.selected === true) ? desiredItem.selected = false : desiredItem.selected = true;
        angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
            if (item !== desiredItem) {
                item.selected = false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Your link function is now empty. Define items on the rootScope instead, this ensures that the isolateScope and your directive interface are working correctly.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $q) {
    elm = angular.element(
      '<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>'
      );
    scope = $rootScope;
    things = [{
            title: 'Scifi',
            description: 'Scifi description'
        }, {
            title: 'Comedy',
            description: 'Comedy description'
        }];
    scope.items = things; // Tests your directive interface

    // compile the template?
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));
```

The behavior of the promise should be tested in a controller test, by mocking the return value of the service. Your problem with the $promise test has been solved.

The actual issue was that you were assuming that $q.defer() gave you the same kind of promise as the angular $http, but that is solved by design instead.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried that but it didn't work, I'm trying to make a reuseable accordion directive that takes in a service and adds a selected property to the first item, but as the items are wrapped in a promise I have to wait for the promise to be resolved before I can access them. Maybe I should create a reusable module which has it's own controller, directive etc and do it that way?

Comment: Actually what I said earlier is rubbish (no change there...) anyway I added the selected property to the controller but left the select function in the directive (not sure if this is the correct way) and so I don't need to test for promise in the directive unit test, but will have to test for it in the controller test hmmmm, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As peter said remove the promise from the directive and add it to the controller

```
angular.module('magicApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Genre',
  function ($scope, Genre) {
      $scope.genres = Genre.query();
      $scope.genres.$promise.then(function () {
          angular.forEach($scope.genres, function (genre) {
              genre.selected = false;
          });
          $scope.genres[0].selected = true;
      });
  }]);
```

This will also allow the controller to specify which tab is selected to begin with.

In the directive

```
var ccAccordion = angular.module("ccAccordion", []);
ccAccordion.directive("ccAccordion", function () {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "components/accordion/accordion.html",
    scope: {
        items: "="
    },
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.select = function (desiredItem) {
            (desiredItem.selected === true) ? desiredItem.selected = false : desiredItem.selected = true;
            angular.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
                if (item !== desiredItem) {
                    item.selected = false;
                }
            });
        };

    }
};
```

});
The directive unit test now looks like this

```
describe('ccAccordion', function () {
var elm, scope, deferred, promise, things;
beforeEach(module('ccAccordion'));

beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (actual, expected) {
                    var classTest = actual.hasClass(expected);
                    classTest ? classTest = true : classTest = false;
                    return {
                        pass: classTest,
                        message: 'Expected ' + angular.mock.dump(actual) + ' to have class ' + expected
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});

// load the templates
beforeEach(module('components/accordion/accordion.html'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $q) {
    elm = angular.element(
      '<cc-accordion items="genres"></cc-accordion>'
      );
    scope = $rootScope;
    scope.genres = [{
            title: 'Scifi',
            description: 'Scifi description'
        }, {
            title: 'Comedy',
            description: 'Comedy description'
        }];
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should create clickable titles', function () {
    var titles = elm.find('.cc-accord h2');

    expect(titles.length).toBe(2);
    expect(titles.eq(0).text().trim()).toBe('Scifi');
    expect(titles.eq(1).text().trim()).toBe('Comedy');
});

it('should bind the content', function () {
 var contents = elm.find('.cc-accord-content div:first-child');

 expect(contents.length).toBe(2);
 expect(contents.eq(0).text().trim()).toBe('Scifi description');
 expect(contents.eq(1).text().trim()).toBe('Comedy description');

 });

 it('should change active content when header clicked', function () {
 var titles = elm.find('.cc-accord h2'),
 divs = elm.find('.cc-accord');

 // click the second header
 titles.eq(1).find('a').click();

 // second div should be active
 expect(divs.eq(0)).not.toHaveClass('active');
 expect(divs.eq(1)).toHaveClass('active');
 });
```

});
And the unit test for main controller now has the added property of selected

```
'use-strict';

describe('magicApp controllers', function () {
// using addMatcher because $resource is not $http and returns a promise
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toEqualData: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: angular.equals(actual, expected)
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});

beforeEach(module('magicApp'));
beforeEach(module('magicServices'));


describe('MainCtrl', function () {
    var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/genres').
          respond([{title: 'Scifi', selected: true}, {title: 'Comedy', selected: false}]);

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));


    it('should create "genres" model with 2 genres fetched from xhr', function () {
        expect(scope.genres).toEqualData([]);
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(scope.genres).toEqualData(
          [{title: 'Scifi', selected: true}, {title: 'Comedy', selected: false}]);
    });
});
```

});